# TypeScript Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript

executing below line gives me `Error:(288, 25) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'CreateValidateObjectType | ((param: string) => CreateValidateObjectType)' has no compatible call signatures.`

`validationMap[FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.LAST_NAME_INPUT]('aaaa')`

Here is the `validationMap` and its type

```
type ValidationMapType = {
  [key: string]: CreateValidateObjectType | ((param: string) => CreateValidateObjectType);
};

const validationMap: ValidationMapType = {
  [FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.FIRST_NAME_INPUT]: createValidationObject({
    required: true,
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 25,
  }),
  [FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.LAST_NAME_INPUT]: (param: string) => createValidationObject({
    required: true,
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 25,
  })
}
```

Calling `validationMap` not as a function is not giving me any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell use what `CreateValidateObjectType` is defined as, but from the error, i assume it's not a function. Since it's not a function, when you do this:

```
validationMap[FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.FIRST_NAME_INPUT]
```

You may or may not get a function. But your code assume it's always a function, because you're immediately and unconditionally calling it:

```
validationMap[FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.FIRST_NAME_INPUT]('aaaa')
```

Typescript is pointing out that, per the types you've defined, you have to check if it's a function first. For example:

```
const validation = validationMap[FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.FIRST_NAME_INPUT];
let result: CreateValidateObjectType;
if (typeof validation === 'function') {
  result = validation('aaaa');
} else {
  result = validation;
}
```

---

If you know ahead of time which properties will be functions and which ones will not, then you could drop the use of the index type, and that way typescript will be able to know "ah yes, the LAST_NAME_INPUT property; this is a function".

```
const validationMap = { // <--- no longer an index type
  [FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.FIRST_NAME_INPUT]: createValidationObject({
    required: true,
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 25,
  }),
  [FORM_ELEMENTS_NAMES.LAST_NAME_INPUT]: (param: string) => createValidationObject({
    required: true,
    minLength: 2,
    maxLength: 25,
  })
}
```

That will mean you don't need to check, but it also means you can't arbitrarily add/remove keys at runtime, like an index type allows.

Comment: Thanks so as I understand union in `ValidationMapType` is not going to help me to use `validationMap` without checking its type?

Comment: Since your union says that the properties might be functions or might not be functions, then you will need to check the type before you can call it. If you know they're always functions, then you could change the type to say that, and then you wouldn't need to check.

Comment: I am so sorry! I've made a mistake while copying the content of `validationMap`. Is current version make any changes?

Comment: It helps to highlight that you have some functions and some nonfunctions, but that was already clear from the type and the type error. Since you don't know whether you have a function or not, then you can't call it. In javascript, it could throw a TypeError when you try to run the code. In typescript, you get a notification when you try to compile the code.

Comment: @akoko i edited in an extra section to my answer. If you know all the types ahead of time, you might be able to drop the index type, and then each property of the map is a single type instead of a union